# error running scala installer on windows

Tags: windows-7, scala

I am trying to use the scala 2.11.2 msi installer (downloaded from the scala site) on windows 7 professional (64 bit).  However, I get the following error when launching the installer:

```
This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows installer package.
```

Any thoughts on whether this may have to do with the msi package, the windows system settnigs (I already have JDK8 installed on the OS).

Comment: Corrupted download? Did you try downloading it again?

Comment: yes I did - same result